# createDesktopLinkAction is not work on non-english language

Tags: install4j

On linux, in non-english language environment, createDesktopLinkAction is not work.
In engliish language environment, createDesktopLinkAction is work well.

Is it bug ? or will be improve on future ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux the *Add a desktop link* action creates a `.desktop` file in the `$HOME/Desktop` directory for each launcher. This will work for freedesktop-compatible window managers.

If that operation does not succeed there will be an error in the `.install4j/installation.log` file.